# Is there a way to search WooCommerce products by their attributes or acf fields?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WooCommerce shop that sells auto parts. Each product is relevant to specific make/model/serial number. The make and model are easy, but I'm having trouble allowing my customers to search serial numbers. Each part may apply to 10k+ serial numbers. In a normal database, I'd just have a start field and end field and to a <=> query, but I can't seem to find that functionality in the WooCommerce ecosystem.

Is there a workaround for this? Can I add all of the possible serial numbers to a field and search that way?

I have tried multiple plugins and some CSS (not my forte) but the answers I seem to be getting from everyone is that their plugins search indexes, not the actual data.

Comment: Of course that functionality is not implemented in WooCommerce as it's very specific to your usage, so you need to build your own custom search by serial number… You should better add first a custom field (custom metadata) to admin single product and build your search on that product custom metadata.